# Get parent node?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I write a script to delete unwanted objects from huge datasets by their id-prefix.

That's how these objects are structured:

```
  <wfsext:Replace vendorId="AdV" safeToIgnore="false">
    <AX_Anschrift gml:id="DENWAEDA0000001G20161222T083308Z">
      <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://www.adv-online.de/">urn:adv:oid:DENWAEDA0000001G</gml:identifier>
      ...
    </AX_Anschrift>
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:FeatureId fid="DENWAEDA0000001G20161222T083308Z" />
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfsext:Replace>
```

I like to delete these full snippet within `<wfsext:Replace>...</wfsext:Replace>`

And there is a code snippet from my script:

```
file = etree.parse(portion_file)
root = file.getroot()
nsmap = root.nsmap.copy()
nsmap['adv'] = nsmap.pop(None)
node = root.xpath(".//adv:geaenderteObjekte/wfs:Transaction", namespaces=nsmap)[0]
for t in node:
    for obj in t:
        objecttype = str(etree.QName(obj.tag).localname)
        if objecttype == 'Filter':
            pass
        else:
            objid = (obj.xpath('@gml:id', namespaces=nsmap))[0][:16]
            if debug:
                print('{} - {}'.format(objid[:16], objecttype))
            if objid[:6] != prefix:
                #parent = obj.getparent()
                t.remove(obj)
```

The `t.remove(obj)` removes `<AX_Anschrift>..</AX_Anschrift>` but not the rest of the object. I tried to get the parent node by using `obj.getparent()` but this gives me an error. How to catch it?

Comment: **What** error do you get when you call `getparent`? Also, can you make the [example complete and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.getparent() is t`, so you don't actually need to call `getparent()`, simply remove the entire object with:

```
node.remove(t)
```

or, if you want to remove the entire `wfs:Transaction`,

```
node.getparent().remove(node)
```

Comment: Sometimes it's too easy! Thank you!